# Activerecord array to a variable.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to get the contents of an activerecord array into a variable.

```
  <%= select_tag :operators,
          options_for_select(@operator_list,
          :selected =>  previous_operators(params[:id], action_name)),
          ),
          {:multiple => true, :size => 11}
  %>
```

previous_operators gets the contents of the operators column (an array)

```
def previous_operators(id, action)
    if action_name != "new" && action_name != "create"                  # prevent error if a new bedsheet line.
      @slitter_bedsheet = SlitterBedsheet.find(id)                       # grab the current bedsheet line
      @previous_operators = Array.new
      @previous_operators = @slitter_bedsheet.operators              # get the keywords for the current bedsheet line
    end

    if @previous_operators.present?                                      
       operators = Array.new
       operators  = eval(@previous_operators)                              
    else
      # operators = ''                                                   
    end

   return operators

  end
```

The content of operators will look something like

```
["", "[\"Chris Mendla\"]"]
```

To summarize, I am trying to get the contents of `@slitter_bedsheet.operators` into the selected line  `:selected =>    previous_operators(params[:id], action_name))`.

So far, the selected option is not working in that no items are shown as already selected.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the eval function. I realize that this is a dangerous function but in this case it is an app that is inside our firewall and the input is coming from a select box. There might be another way of doing this but this will work for now.

`:selected =>    eval(previous_operators(params[:id], action_name))`